# Problems with the attribute "placeholder" of an <p:inputText tag when the value of the inputText is empty

Tags: html, css, jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF Mojarra 2.3.9.SP02 with PrimeFaces 7.0 running on Wildfly 17 with the PrimeFaces's own  Sapphire template.

I have a severe problem with one <p:inputText element in my form, for which I have specified a placeholder, and whose initial value is empty. This is the first input field just below the panel group with the title "Kontaktperson" as shown in the attachment

[image]

Below is my minimal working example:

=========== .xhtml file ==================

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    </f:facet>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <h:outputScript name="js/nanoscroller.js" library="sapphire-layout" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/layout.js" library="sapphire-layout" />
    <h:outputScript name="js/ripple.js" library="sapphire-layout" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <style>
        .md-inputfield_marg_top{
            margin-top: 10px;
        }
    </style>          
                
  <div class="ui-g ui-fluid">   
        <div class="card card-w-title">
            <h:form id="resultsFormId">
                    
                        <div class="card-title">Firmendaten bearbeiten</div> 
                              <p:fieldset legend="Kontaktperson" toggleable="true" toggleSpeed="500">
                              <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2">
                                   <div class="ui-inputgroup">
                                      <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">
                                          <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
                                      </span>
                                      <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield md-inputfield_marg_top">
                                          <p:inputText value="#{fdTestBean.titel}" placeholder="Mag."/>
                                          <label>Titel</label>
                                      </h:panelGroup>     
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-2"/>
                              <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-8">
                                   <div class="ui-inputgroup">
                                      <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">
                                          <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
                                      </span>
                                      <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield md-inputfield_marg_top">
                                          <p:inputText value="#{fdTestBean.qualifikation}" />
                                          <label>Qualifikation</label>
                                      </h:panelGroup>     
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
                                   <div class="ui-inputgroup">
                                      <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">
                                          <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
                                      </span>
                                      <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield md-inputfield_marg_top">
                                          <p:inputText value="#{fdTestBean.vorname}"/>
                                          <label>Vorname</label>
                                      </h:panelGroup>     
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6">
                                   <div class="ui-inputgroup">
                                      <span class="ui-inputgroup-addon">
                                          <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
                                      </span>
                                      <h:panelGroup styleClass="md-inputfield md-inputfield_marg_top">
                                          <p:inputText value="#{fdTestBean.nachname}"/>
                                          <label>Nachname</label>
                                      </h:panelGroup>     
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                          </p:fieldset>
           </h:form>
      </div>
   </div>
    
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/nanoscroller.css" library="sapphire-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/ripple.css" library="sapphire-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/grid.css" library="sapphire-layout" />
    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout-#{guestPreferences.layout}.css" library="sapphire-layout" />
   </h:body>
</html>
```

And my backing bean here:

```
package at.home.digest.web.ave.makler.firma;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("fdTestBean")
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
public class FDTestBean implements Serializable {

    private String titel;

    private String qualifikation;

    private String vorname;

    private String nachname;

    public String getTitel() {
        return titel;
    }

    public void setTitel(String titel) {
        this.titel = titel;
    }

    public String getQualifikation() {
        return qualifikation;
    }

    public void setQualifikation(String qualifikation) {
        this.qualifikation = qualifikation;
    }

    public String getVorname() {
        return vorname;
    }

    public void setVorname(String vorname) {
        this.vorname = vorname;
    }

    public String getNachname() {
        return nachname;
    }

    public void setNachname(String nachname) {
        this.nachname = nachname;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Share the relevant, rendered HTML and the relevant CSS.

Comment: @JasperdeVries please refer to the minimal working example provided above. Thank you!

Comment: This feels like you are using a newer PF version than the Saphire template was designed for and somehow the CSS isn't correct for the labels when there is a value.  Feels like a bug in the CSS of the Saphire template?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldnt't all those inputs only have a placeholder **OR** a value? It just posts them both if your value is set. Or you switch placeholders with your values.

Comment: Well the placeholder is necessary when the initial value is empty - as a hint to the user what the inut should look like

Comment: you could ask if the value is empty -> set placeholder to "example" with php or something like this

Comment: but the problem is there even if the value is not empty. (however less severe)